# Robot follow person

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor

I want to make a wagon that follows a person. I have considered GPS with a differential but I don't think the resolution (10 meters at best) is adequate. IR would be confused by reflections an sunlight, as this would be an outside device. Ultrasonic would maybe work but would need to be specific to one person, not just "blob" detection. The best I have thought of so far is a transmitter (433 MHz) followed by a pair of receivers triangulating on signal strength. Any thoughts? I want to control things with a Pi or Arduino, or both.

Answer (score 0):

If using rf triangulation I would consider static satellite receivers so that a decent triangulation of both person and vehicle could be compared and adjustments sent to the vehicle.

Of course the static transceivers would have to encompass the full field or range that the system could be expected to work within and this is a limitation.

Trying to triangulate from a small vehicle needs  possibly too much precision for it to work with any degree of accuracy.